# routingProvider not working with controller form separate file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem with loading controllers to a specific route in AngularJS when using `routeProvider` service. It works fine if I define the controller in the same file as the file I declared the module in, but I want the controllers to be in a separate file. When I try to load them from a separate file I get an error, saying the controller was not found.

Here's my code:

(pixelApp.js)

```
'use strict';

var pixelApp = angular.module('pixelApp',['ngRoute'])
.config(function routing($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.when('/',
        {
            templateUrl: '../directory/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCTRL'
        }
    );

    $routeProvider.otherwise(
        {
            redirectTo: '/'
        }
    );
});
```

(homeCTRL.js)

```
'use strict';

pixelApp.controller('homeCTRL',
   function homeCTRL($scope)
   {
       $scope.message = "Welcome to home.";
   }
);
```

(index.html)

```
<body>

<ng-view></ng-view>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- App Module -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pixelApp.js"></script>
<!-- App Module -->

<!-- View Controllers -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/homeCTRL.js" />
<!-- View Controllers -->



</body>
```

I have looked spent a lot of time looking for a solution and couldn't find it, it would be greatly appreciated if anybody could help me out with this.

Comment: how did you get pixel app in your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is simply your script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/homeCTRL.js" />
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/homeCTRL.js"></script>
```

Comment: You were right. thanks! hours spent because of a simple misstake.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `use strict` and referencing undefined variables.

(pixelApp.js)

```
var pixelApp = window.pixelApp = angular.module('pixelApp',['ngRoute'])
```

...

(homeCTRL.js)

```
window.pixelApp.controller(....)
```